# Linux Write Something on multiple files

Tags: linux, debian

I have a file "atest.txt" that have some text..

I want to print this text at files "asdasd.txt asgfaya.txt asdjfusfdgh.txt asyeiuyhavujh.txt"

This files is not exist on my server..

I'm running Debian.. What can i do?

Answer (score 9):

Use the *tee*(1) command, which duplicates its standard input to standard output and any files specified on the command line.  E.g.

```
printf "Hello\nthis is a test\nthank you\n"
  | tee test1.txt test2.txt $OTHER_FILES >/dev/null
```

Using your example:

```
cat atest.txt
  | tee asdasd.txt asgfaya.txt asdjfusfdgh.txt asyeiuyhavujh.txt >/dev/null
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind my editing making the answer clearer given the example

Comment: UUOC: tee test1.txt test2.txt <atest.txt >/dev/null

Answer (score 2):

If anyone would like to write same thing to all files in dir:

```
printf 'your_text' | tee *
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can write

```
#!/bin/bash
$TEXT="hello\nthis is a test\nthank you"
for i in `seq 1 $1`; do echo -e $TEXT >text$i.txt; done
```

EDIT (in response of question change)

If you can't determine programmatically the names of the target files then you can use this script it:

```
#!/bin/bash
ORIGIN=$1;
shift
for i in `seq $#`; do cp "$ORIGIN" "$1"; shift; done
```

you can use it this way:
script_name origin_file dest_file1 second_dest_file 'third file' ...

If you are wondering why there are the double quotes into the cp command, it is for cope with filename containing spaces

Answer (score 1):

From your bash prompt:

```
for f in test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt; do echo -e "hello\nworld" >> $f; done
```

If the text lives in atest.txt then do:

```
for f in test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt; do cat atest.txt >> $f; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it simply:

```
cp atest.txt asdasd.txt 
cp atest.txt asgfaya.txt
cp atest.txt asdjfusfdgh.txt
cp atest.txt asyeiuyhavujh.txt
```

?